# SAPUI5: Binding JSON file HANA DB to SAPUI5 Chart

Tags: json, sapui5

Heyho!

I tried all the day to bind the data of a JSON file to the data model of a SAPUI5 chart but without success. I miss the link between the JSON file and the dataset by path.

Added is the file containing the standalone code but without the json file which just contains calday and counter with some data. There seems no problem by defining the data directly in the script as data and refering in the dataset to it. Which I tried lately as you recognize at the /data path.

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <title>Flattened DataSet bound to OData Entity with filter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" type="text/javascript" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.viz" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_goldreflection">
    </script>
    <script>
    var oModelJSON  = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModelJSON.loadData(file.json);

    var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
        dimensions: [{
            axis: 1,
            name: 'Calendar Day',
            value: "{calday}"
        }],
        measures: [{
            name: 'Counter',
            value: '{counter}'
        }],
        data: {
            path: "/data"
        }
    });

    var oChart = new sap.viz.ui5.Column({
        width: "80%",
        height: "400px",
        plotArea: {
            'colorPalette': d3.scale.category20().range()
        },
        title: {
            visible: true,
            text: 'Counter per Calendar Day'
        },
        dataset: oDataset
    });

    oChart.setModel(oModelJSON ); 
    oChart.placeAt("content");
    </script>

</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: It would be good to include the json file as well, or perhaps include some of the json inline in your code.